# How to search an index by value in two dimensional array in php

Tags: php

I have a function to get description of courier , all records fetched about courier and are stored in `$couriers` . $courier is two dimensional array since it containing all rows of table couriers .

```
[
{
"id":"1",
"name":"DTDC",
"description":"Automatically inserted by application ",
"bloked":"false"
},
{
"id":"2",
"name":"Ecomm",
"description":"Nothing",
"bloked":"false"
},
{
"id":"3",
"name":"MarginPrice",
"description":"Local only",
"bloked":"false"
}
]
```

> Now , i have to fetch decription of courier whose id is given . For
>   this purpose , i must know the index of the records .. I tried it
>   using array_search but "hard time" . So , i ask for help to give idea
>   to know the index of that records in array

```
 function getCourierDescriptionById($id)
    {   global $couriers;
        if($couriers==null)
        {
            loadCourier($id);
        }
        $index=array_search($id,$couriers);// Here is the problem
        return isset($couriers[$index]['description'])?
                                            $couriers[$index]['description']:null;      
    }
```

Comment: what does your array looks like ?

Comment: append here your sample array in question

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, I strongly recommend that you had a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works and how to write your question so it receives the best possible answers it can  :)

Comment: now , i included the array format in question what i do have ..

Comment: @rashmisingh check answer to easy to find from array using id you can return only description also........ Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You $courier variable is not an array , it is a json string , so dcode it first which turns it to in php array.

```
$couriers = json_decode($couriers,true);
```

Now your function , can be defined as below , by using [array_map](http://www.w3schools.com/Php/func_array_map.asp)

```
 function getCourierDescriptionById($id)
    {   global $couriers;
        $args=func_num_args();
        if($couriers==null)
        {
            loadCourier($id);
        }
        $index=array_search($id,array_map("getAllCourierId",$couriers));
        return isset($couriers[$index]['description'])?
                   $couriers[$index]['description']:null;       
    }
```

Now the function who is bounded with array_map as below

```
 function getAllCourierId($arr)
        {
            return $arr['id'];
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this way easy to use

```
$j = '[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"DTDC",
    "description":"Automatically inserted by application ",
    "bloked":"false"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Ecomm",
    "description":"Nothing",
    "bloked":"false"
    },
    {
    "id":"3",
    "name":"MarginPrice",
    "description":"Local only",
    "bloked":"false"
    }
    ]';
    $arr = json_decode($j,true);
    $courier =array();
    foreach($arr as $sample){
        $courier[$sample['id']] = $sample;
    }
    //make sure your courier variable has id which you want to find "Its easy to search"

    function getCourierDescriptionById($id)
        {   global $courier;

            return isset($courier[$id])? $courier[$id]:null;      
        }
        print_r(getCourierDescriptionById(3));//function call which want to find
```

Your $courier variable has change for Easy to find, Which is contain array like that:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => DTDC
            [description] => Automatically inserted by application 
            [bloked] => false
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Ecomm
            [description] => Nothing
            [bloked] => false
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => MarginPrice
            [description] => Local only
            [bloked] => false
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$jsonArray = '[
    {
    "id":"1",
    "name":"DTDC",
    "description":"Automatically inserted by application ",
    "bloked":"false"
    },
    {
    "id":"2",
    "name":"Ecomm",
    "description":"Nothing",
    "bloked":"false"
    },
    {
    "id":"3",
    "name":"MarginPrice",
    "description":"Local only",
    "bloked":"false"
    }
    ]';
    $arrData = json_decode($jsonArray,true);
    print_r(searchForId('3',$arrData,'id'));

function searchForId($id, $array,$field) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val[$field] === $id) {
           return $val['description'];
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```